# Angular application not starting from Docker

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I'm new to both docker and Angular application. 
I had installed **docker CE**. I have made a base project in Angular using:-

```
ng new my-app
```

Now I pulled a docker image using :-

```
docker pull node
```

whose link can be found here :- https://hub.docker.com/r/library/node/

When I ran the following command -

```
docker run -d -p 8080:4200 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

Container logs show:-

```
    ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
2018-01-12T16:21:13.572303587Z 
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-01-12T16:21:43.248Z
Hash: a3cbcf9f66fb3ceaaf7e
Time: 14699ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 21.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 551 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 33.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.42 MB [initial] [rendered]
2018-01-12T16:21:43.314312640Z 
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

But when I run localhost:8080. Nothing shows up. 
When I stop the docker container and just start the project - using npm start, the home page loads at localhost:4200

Comment: Is there any docker logs after you open `localhost:8080` ?

Comment: nothing else I guess

Comment: can you ping localhost:8080 from your local?

Comment: in case of docker machine, we would access the page using hostIP:port.

Comment: But in case of docker CE i don't find any command regarding finding any ip

Comment: Have you done anything to the Dockerfile?

Comment: nope. I just pulled the image, and started the container. Is there a possibility that node version in Dockerfile is older? But I guess there should be some command in the docker file to get the latest node files

Comment: When I do docker ps, it shows under PORTS :- 0.0.0.0:80->4200/tcp . Is that an okay thing?

Comment: Yes, you may be using an older node version.